# libusb-1.x VS openUsb

Tags: python, linux, usb, max

Have a few questions about libusb VS openusb

I'm the author of a project called Berry4all that allows tethering for Blackberries Via USB.

Cuurrently I'm using libusb-0.x but i'd like /need to migrate to either libusb1.x OR libopenusb ... but I'm not sure which to pick

Some of the things I need:
- Linux support
- Mac OSX support (need it to work and be able to package it)
- Python bindings

Opinions on either and why pick one over the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for libusb-1 because it seems architecturally simpler, more actively maintained, more portable and more mainstream than OpenUSB. Their [webpage](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/libusb-1.0) lists successful projects based on it, and a small comparison to OpenUSB you might find useful.